# Error while trying to access Elemntor-pro base-widget.php from a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm building a custom plugin for elementor.

the line `use ElementorPro\Base\BaseWidget;` throwed the following error:

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 17 of the file /home/herbalhe/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-nav-menu-with-logo/widgets/nav-menu-with-logo.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Class 'ElementorPro\Base\Base_Widget' not found in /home/herbalhe/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-nav-menu-with-logo/widgets/nav-menu-with-logo.php:17

when I tried to access it with an require statement `require '../../elementor-pro/base/base-widget.php';` I received the following error:

> An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 3 of the file /home/herbalhe/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-nav-menu-with-logo/widgets/nav-menu-with-logo.php. Error message: require(): Failed opening required '../../elementor-pro/base/base-widget.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear').

this is the faulty code:

```
namespace ElementorNavMenuWithLogo\Widgets;
require '../../elementor-pro/base/base-widget.php';
require '../../elementor-pro/plugin.php';
use Elementor\Controls_Manager;
use Elementor\Core\Schemes;
use Elementor\Core\Responsive\Responsive;
use Elementor\Group_Control_Border;
use Elementor\Group_Control_Box_Shadow;
use Elementor\Group_Control_Typography;
use ElementorPro\Base\Base_Widget;
use ElementorPro\Plugin;
```

My questions are: why the code doesn't throws an error when it executes `use Elementor\Core\Schemes;` for example, but it does when it executes `use ElementorPro\Base\BaseWidget;`, and how could I access ElementorPro files when my plugin file is within a different directory?
thank you for helping.

Comment: The problem on line 3 is the one that you need to solve, it is causing your other problems. First, probably use `require_once`, just to make sure you don't cause another problem elsewhere. Then, are you absolutely sure that there's a file at `/home/herbalhe/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/base/base-widget.php`

Comment: The file is definitely there

Comment: Okay, then the next step is to check the permissions on the file to make sure your PHP process has what is needed. If you are on *nix, it is usually 0664, I think

Comment: Now its the time to admit that I don't have a green clue on how to check for the file permissions, other than the tool that cPaneli gives (has the same permission as the entire folder. 
this is the Error message:

`Warning: require_once($root/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/base/base-widget.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/herbalhe/public_html/develop-mode/wp-content/plugins/elementor-nav-menu-with-logo/widgets/nav-menu-with-logo.php on line 4`